# Actionscript3 - Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I want build a game, but i get this errors:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at project.game.players.controllers::myPlayerController/onEnterFrame()
```

This is my class: http://pastebin.com/x0kpaDg2

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array `clicked` is not initialized. And for associative arrays preferable to use `Object` type.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that some of your object is not instantiated. Thus, it is null. And thus, you have this exception because you are trying to access it. This is kind of problem which reasons is not that hard to find. Just debug your app.